# Implementing AJAX via POST request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am reading a book that describes the procedure to implement Ajax via POST request. This is code:

name of file: **ajaxtest.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src ="xhr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>LOADING A WEBPAGE INTO A DIV</h1>

<div id="info">This is going to be replaced </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

url = "ajaxtest.php"

params = "url=oreilly.com"

request = new ajaxRequest()

request.open("POST",url,true)

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-wwww-form-urlencode")

request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(this.status == 200)
        {
            if(this.responseText != null)
            {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Ajax error: No data received ")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Ajax Error " + this.statusText)
        }
    }
}

request.send(params)


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The example of that book also has 2 lines **i removed** after reading some other articles:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
```

The **ajaxRequest** function is saved in a separate .js file named **xhr.js**:

```
function ajaxRequest()
{
try
{
    // fon NON-IE browsers
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
}
catch(e1)
{
    try
    {
        //for IE6+ browser
        var request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    }
    catch(e2)
    {
        try
        {
            //for IE5
            var request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch(e3)
        {
            //No AJAX support 
            var request = false
        }
    }
}
return request
}
```

And the **ajaxtest.php** file is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
echo file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['url']);

echo "test1";
}

echo "test2";

echo $_POST['url'];
?>
```

The thing is that, as soon as i execute the **ajaxtest.html**, the part "This is going to be replaced", it disappears (which is correct), but after that what i get is the part of the **ajaxtest.php** that is outside the **if(isset())**. And when it reaches the echo **$_POST['url']** outside the **if(isset())** i get the following error:

**Notice: Undefined index: url in C:\wamp\www\ajaxtest.php on line 11**

Ofcourse the **test2** is printed on the page.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't **$_POST['url']** be available in the **ajaxtest.php** script as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="xhr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>LOADING A WEBPAGE INTO A DIV</h1>

<div id="info">This is going to be replaced </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
url = "ajaxtest.php";
params = "url="+encodeURIComponent("oreilly.com");

request = new ajaxRequest();
request.open("POST",url,true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4) {
        if(this.status == 200) {
            if(this.responseText != null) {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            } else {
                alert("Ajax error: No data received ")
            }
        } else {
            alert("Ajax Error " + this.statusText)
        }
    }
}

request.send(params);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajaxtest.php**

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $_POST = array_map("urldecode",$_POST);
    echo file_get_contents("http://".$_POST['url']);
} else {
    echo "test2";
}
?>
```

First, you need to encode your parameters before sending them through ajax.

Second, when getting the parameters in php you need to decode them.

Third, you have misspelled the content-type.

Comment: Tanatos, its working now. Is there a tutorial explaining the encoding/decoding procedure you mentioned above? Cause in the book i read i see nothing similar..

Comment: Well, easy to remember, if you are sending strings that can include empty spaces, dashes, commas or any non-alphanumeric characters , through a URL request it needs to be encoded (by url request I mean get or javascript ajax).

As for encoding/decoding, based on the functions you can find in the code above you will be able to find the opposing functions as well.

Good luck with your learning ! :)

Comment: @Tantos: Easier to remember: If you write an URL it needs to be an URL, so URL encoded. If you write HTML, it needs to be HTML, so HTML encoded. If you write JS, it needs to be JS, so JS encoded. And so on and so forth. It's always, ever, that thing then that encoded. Everthing else is coding like shooting with a shotgun. Imprecise, high impact, and many collateral debugging questions on SO afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is wrong:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-wwww-form-urlencode")
//                                                                         ^
```

It should be:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded")
```

With the wrong content type you can still tell PHP to parse it anyway:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $data);
echo $data['url'];
```

But setting the correct content type will be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the same javascript format from the book you are reading, you could define your 'params' as such:

```
params = JSON.stringify({url:'oreilly.com'});//SEND AS JSON OBJECT
```

and in the PHP file:

```
        <?php
        $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($request_body);//DECODE JSON OBJECT
        $url = $data->url;//EXTRACT THE "URL" VALUE FROM DECODED JSON OBJECT
        if(isset($url))
        {
        echo file_get_contents("http://".$url);
        echo "test1";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the Jquery AJAX methods makes using ajax communication a lot simpler.

This can simply be done using the following line of code: (for a web connected site, if it is for local use you would need to download the file locally)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

you would then use the following code to setup your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path", 
    type: "POST", //http verb, can be any of the standard verbs, eg, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE... 
    data:{data1:data1_value, data2:data2_value}, //any post data to send with request
    async: true, 
    dataType:'json', //data format expected from server
    success: function (data) {
        //code to execute on success (the data variable contains any data returned by the server
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //code to handle errors goes here
    },
});
```

Comment: I know that using JQuery simplifies everything, but right now i am in the procedure to learn the basics of Javascript (and AJAX), so i could better understand JQuery later..